# Where should questions like this be posted (should it be posted?)

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I asked a question and realized that the question is perhaps too broad or off-topic.

The wording was:

> We have a java application, a simple jar running in an "embedded"
>   environment on a simple box with limited capabilities. The box can run
>   linux with preinstalled Java, bash, and busybox.
>
> We plan on pushing OTA updates to these boxes, we initially plan on
>   rolling out 100-1000 boxes.
>
> We need a solution to allow the boxes to download and install new
>   updates to the jar autonomously and fool-proof. We do have possibility
>   to remotely access the boxes in case of failures, but we prefer to
>   avoid this as it is difficult.
>
> How can such a scheme be created or does there exist some tools
>   already capable of this?

An obvious issue is that there is no single right answer. 
Is there a place for such questions on Stack Exchange (perhaps with a different wording)?

Comment: It's certainly too broad for SO. There are numerous ways for pushing or puling such updates.

Comment: Yes, there are numerous ways. But I am still looking for input on at least one of these ways. So is there a place for broad questions?

Comment: You might want to try [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/)... be sure to get a feel for it before you ask though.

Comment: @Deduplicator The chat always seems so scary, but it might be the place. What do you mean be get a feel for it though?

Comment: Look for a likely chat, read the faq and a bit of the back-log, and then try to decide whether your first inclination was actually right. Repeat as neccessary. And then if you are in a good room for it, ask your question in the appropriate way.

Answer (score -2):

https://serverfault.com/ might be a good place to ask - it's the systems/network admin version of SO.

Comment: I would have trouble recommending SF. Their current scope definition crisis appears to revolve around the question of if one has the job title of 'system administrator' rather than 'full stack developer' or 'devops'.  At the very least, check out in their chat room (wait, no, that's inactive) or ask on http://meta.serverfault.com/ *first* to see if the question is on topic for the site. It could avoid a bit of mismatched expectations for posting on the main site.